# How to split a date from String by using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, date, split

In the string below I want to keep date in separate varible by separating from the total String.

```
    String text="The client start date is 13/10/2018";
    String[] effectiveDateText=text.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<effectiveDateText.length;i++){
        String effectiveDate=effectiveDateText.length-1;
    }
```

I get a compiler error message saying

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

What is the correct way to get date into a separate variable?

Comment: string singleDate = effectiveDateText[(effectiveDateText.length)-1] is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Your question is clear now, and I have voted for reopening.

Comment: If this is for a Selenium test, why not go the other way? If you want to check that the date is `13/10/2018`, concatenate the text in front and check if the text you get from Selenium matches. `"The client start date is " + expectedDate`. Or maybe test `text.endsWith("13/10/2018")`.

Comment: [Ayush Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420782/ayush-goel) would like to say: Selenium is not used for splitting strings. Read string manipulations in Java or whichever programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it now after lots of modifications,

use this simple,

```
string SingleDate = effectiveDateText[(effectiveDateText.length)-1]
```

Dont forget effectiveDateText is an Array of Strings, You need '.[ int ]'
on it.
Still i suggest you to use Regex for this if you are not sure where your Date placed is,

```
String regex = "(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(m.group(1));
}
```

From your client start date and your split code method,
It seems you are doing split at wrong character,
And you got number of dates that need to be splitted,

You supposed to split at '/' rather than splitting at ' '

Try using,

```
String FullDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText(); // FullDate = 13/10/2018
String[] effectiveDateText=FullDate.split("/");
String Day = effectiveDateText[0]; // Day = 13    
List<Date> dList = new List<>();
```

i am just curious why you used for loop you may use forEach instead, 
Is there more dates are present in FullDate variable.
(like FullDate = "13/10/2018 13/10/2018 13/10/2018 13/10/2018" something Right)

```
for(String effectiveDate : effectiveDateText){
   // effectiveDate contains date of your like
   effectiveDate = effectiveDate.Trim();
   Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(effectiveDate);
   dList.add(date1);
}
```

I hope this answered your question
You will get all dates in List dList;

Comment: Hi..in this question i want to split entire date from string value, not only day

Comment: what do get in the " FullDate " variable Please provide that in your question, or your html elemnt stucture is need for more help and clarification of your issue.

Comment: Hi Ahish, Sorry for no clarity ..can you check it once

Comment: ok i mean this command  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText()  gives you bunch of dates which are separated by " " i.e. 'space' right

I want, what actual TEXT this command returns to you.

Comment: yes from that total text i want to separate date only..nd i want to keep that in one variable

Comment: string singleDate = effectiveDateText[(effectiveDateText.length)-1]  is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *text* **The client start date is 13/10/2018** to store the *date* in separate varible you can use the **`split()`** method and can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class Split_in_Java  
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          String text="The client start date is 13/10/2018";
          String[] parts = text.split(" ");
          System.out.println(parts[parts.length-1]);
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  13/10/2018
  ```